# How do I redirect with mod_rewrite to a document and set the GET parameter?

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, webserver

So I'm going straight to business. Both tested and confirmed on XAMPP (Windows 7 32-Bit) and MAMP (OS X Snow Leopard), both newest versions. I have the following site structure:

```
/op/.htaccess
/op/index.php
/op/profile.php
```

The paths are the absolute paths from Apache document root.

My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$ profile.php?alias=$1
```

When I request the site via *http://localhost:8888/op/* the document *index.php* is opened. That's okay. When I request via *http://localhost:8888/op/example* the document *profile.php* is opened, that's also fine. And there is set up a GET parameter with the name *alias* just like desired. But it's value is simply empty! Like this:

```
http://localhost:8888/op/profile.php?alias=
```

So I just want to pass on the last part of the url as a GET variable that it looks like this for the server:

```
http://localhost:8888/op/profile.php?alias=example
```

I am slowly getting desperate. I am fighting with this since two and a half hours now. Either it is a wrong server configuration or a real silly mistake. I guess it's the regular expression, but I just don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a regex thing, your htaccess should look like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ profile.php?alias=$1
```

The `$1` at the end of the string matches the first sub-pattern, but you didn't indicate any sub-pattern. The first set of parenthesis is the first sub-pattern.

Additionally, you may wish to indicate a `RewriteBase`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ profile.php?alias=$1
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You are my hero of the day!